# Preventing combobox from updating text

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I would like my combobox to reset its `selectedindex` to  `-1` and open a form when the last item in the dropdown list is selected. I'm currently achieving it with this:

```
Private Sub cmbPrdMnu_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbPrdMnu.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cmbPrdMnu.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        If cmbPrdMnu.SelectedItem.Equals("new...") Then
            cmbPrdMnu.SelectedIndex = -1
            'cmbPrdMnu.Text = ""
            frmManufacturer.Show()
            'cmbPrdCat.ResumeLayout()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

My problem is the combobox actually displays the selected item before it removes the text and then opens the form. Please how can i prevent it from displaying the selected item?

Thanks

Comment: Weird, I just tested this on Win10 / .NET 4.5.1 and it worked fine. Have you tried using `cmbPrdMnu.Refresh()` to force the combobox to update?

Comment: Hello Saragis, i just upgraded to .NET 4.6 and tried `cmbPrdMnu.Refresh()`, but it doesn't change anything. In fact, it's the `cmbPrdMnu.SelectedIndex = -1` that removes the text from the combobox. I don't want the client to see "new..." displayed at all on the combobox. I guess I'm dropping the code in the wrong EventHandler, but i don't seem to get my way around it. Please help, anybody.

Comment: @Saragis, this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14255/ComboBox-firing-events-when-hovering-on-the-dropdo) has an app with a custom combobox to does something similar to what i want. I converted the custom source code from c# to vb, but encountered an error. Please view the links below: [vb code](http://www.filefactory.com/file/5foocv20cmvd/Custom%20combobox%20%28vb.net%29.txt)  and  [c# code](http://www.filefactory.com/file/6417cgan6655/Custom%20combobox%20%28cs.net%29.txt)

Comment: Hi, ok so I misunderstood your original question. So you're trying to have something like a hover-index changed event right? I took a look at your VB class and the issue can be solved by calling `RaiseEvent Hover(Me, e)` in `OnHover` in the `myCustomCombobox` class. All the other code is no longer necessary. Further, you'll need to add a Sub that handles the `cmbPrdMnu.Hover` event in your Form. This should work.

Comment: @Saragis, the code in  `OnHover` is now
           `RaiseEvent Hover(Me, e)`    which cleared my error.    2. In my form,    `Private Sub cmbPrdMnu_Hover(sender As Object, e As Custom.HoverEventArgs) Handles cmbPrdMnu.MouseHover    
If e.itemIndex = DirectCast(sender, Custom.myCustomCombobox).Items(e.itemIndex) - 1 Then    
MsgBox("gotcha!")    
End If    
End Sub`    
gives this error:    `Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'My_Project.Custom.HoverEventArgs'.`    When i remove the `Handles...` clause, nothing happens on mouse hover.

Comment: Hi, you need the `Hover` event instead of the `MouseHover` event. This is the custom event created by using the custom combobox.

Comment: This is the signature `Private Sub cmbPrdMnu_Hover(sender As Object, e As Custom.HoverEventArgs) Handles cmbPrdMnu.Hover`

Comment: Hello Saragis, `Hover` is underlined, saying    `Event Hover cannot be found.`    What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure, make sure your combobox is actually of type `myCustomCombobox`. It should work fine then, since I did the same yesterday while testing this

Comment: I thought the `DirectCast(sender, Custom.myCustomCombobox)` as seen above converts cmbPrdMnu to myCustomCombobox.

Comment: No the control actually needs to be of type `myCustomCombobox`, not just `Combobox`. You can change the type in the Designer file of your form.

Comment: Your suggestion removed the error. However, I noticed that the hover event doesn't get the index after the 9th item - it freezes on the 9th - and that will prevent me from achieving my goal. I guess I have to tweak the `WndProc` Sub in the VB class. My question still remains: `How do i stop MouseClick  event from changing the combobox text when it hovers over the last item and clicks it?` I truly appreciate your help so far.

Comment: @Saragis: hi, after some research, i found a solution to the freezing. After commenting    `OrElse ((oldYPos > Me.ItemHeight * Me.MaxDropDownItems) AndAlso Me.DropDownStyle <> ComboBoxStyle.Simple)` (line 126 Col 101 Ch 101 in VB class), i can now get the index of the last item in cmbPrdMnu. But how can i override the `selectedindex eventhandler` so that it doesn't display the last item if it is eventually clicked by the user?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, you could try to override the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event in `myCustomCombobox` but I'm not sure how you'll be able to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the delphi technique Saragis & I (any other unknown experts, if any) applied for days now, I carefully went through the combobox control and stumbled upon the `SelectionChangeCommitted` Event and that saved me a whole lot of hair-pulling days. For those with similar issues, here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmbPrdMnu_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbPrdMnu.SelectionChangeCommitted
    cmbPrdMnu.SelectedIndex = cmbPrdMnu.Items.Count - 1 Then 
        cmbPrdMnu.SelectedIndex = -1 
        'Do some other stuff
        'Else
        'Do an alternative stuff here
    End If    
End Sub
```

@Saragis: This totally eliminated the need for my custom VB class. Thanks for your effort; I do appreciate.